# ShellExecute (and ShellExecuteEx) do nothing with my URL

Tags: c++, windows, browser, shellexecute, c++builder-xe7

I'm creating a project with C++Builder XE7, in which a user can click on a button to open a web link, e.g. to open a support page, or to share his experience on a social media. For that, I use the `ShellExecute()` function, and it works well, except for one button.

When I click on this button, simply nothing happens. The `ShellExecute()` function returns without error (the returned value is 42), but my default browser does not open, and the web page isn't shown at all.

Here is my `ShellExecute()` implementation

```cpp
const HINSTANCE result = ::ShellExecute(handle, "open", url.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

I also tried the `ShellExecuteEx()` function:

```cpp
::SHELLEXECUTEINFO info;
std::memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
info.hwnd   = handle;
info.lpVerb = "open";
info.lpFile = url.c_str();
info.nShow  = SW_SHOWDEFAULT;

if (!::ShellExecuteEx(&info))
```

The `url` parameter contains the website link I am trying to open. For security reasons, I cannot post it here as a sample, however I tested it in my browser (FireFox) and it works well. On the other hand, if I execute my code by just replacing the `url` content with Google's website, all works as expected.

The `handle` is just the `Handle` parameter of the parent frame.

I also tried to tweak the `ShellExecute/Ex()` parameters, like the `hwnd` and `nShow` fields, but no change.

Can anybody point me to what is wrong?

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]? Also what is you default browser? What happens if you do Start-Run and then type some url such as `http://www.stackoverflow.com/`.

Comment: I cannot publish more code, unfortunately. The code before the call to ShellExecute() is just the building of the URL, inside a function, and I'm not allowed to show it. On the caller side, this function just is called inside the button event, with the handle of the button parent. So the above code is already the most simplest code sample I'm allowed to provide.

Comment: And all is fine with my Windows configuration. As I said in the above post, my default browser is FireFox, and Start-Run opens it with the provided link as expected. And also, the same ShellExecute() in my code works just well with a simple link, like http://www.google.com. But the behavior of ShellExecute() itself is very strange with my url: why it returns without doing nothing, and without error? May be a ShellExecute() bug?

Comment: Does that url include query string? You don't have to post the exact URL, just post a similar one or modify existing url and paste it

Comment: The url is formatted like this:http: // www. mysite.xxx/selectPage.php?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy&...&argX=a text containing \"quotes\" and some %26amp%3b special chars!

Comment: It you care about proper error reporting, call `ShellExecuteEx`.

Comment: I already tried that, the situation is the same: ShellExecuteEx() returns no errors, but also do nothing

Comment: _a text containing \"quotes\"_ ... have you actually encoded the double quotes or is this just how you copied the string from your C++ source?

Comment: In `argX=a text containing ...`, are you encoding space characters and other reserved characters in `%HH` format? If not, you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The url is formatted like this: http:// www.
> mysite.xxx/selectPage.php?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy&...&argX=a text containing
> "quotes" and some %26amp%3b special chars!

In this example you have to **URL-encode the double quotes and the spaces** because these are not valid characters for the [query part of an URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4).

Fix it by replacing double quotes with `%22` and spaces with `%20`. I suggest to use a function like [`UrlEscape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773774(v=vs.85).aspx) to properly encode the URL.

Although most browsers have an error tolerance for user input and will also accept an URL which does not have valid encoding, it's better to strictly follow the spec because you are not guaranteed that tolerance.

In addition, the double quotes will make problems when the URL is passed as a command-line argument to the command associated with the URL protocol. This is because **double quotes are reserved characters for defining command-line parameters that contain spaces**.

For instance, on my machine the `http` protocol is associated with the following command (see `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command`):

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -osint -url "%1"`

You can see that the double quotes are already used to enclose the last parameter, which obviously gets messed up if you have **unencoded** double quotes within the URL.

Example for correctly encoding an URL for use with `ShellExecuteEx()`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

int main()
{
    ::CoInitialize(nullptr);

    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW info{ sizeof(info) };
    info.fMask  = SEE_MASK_NOASYNC; // because we exit process after ShellExecuteEx()
    info.lpVerb = L"open";
    info.lpFile = L"http://www.google.de/search?q=ShellExecuteEx%20URL%20%22double%20quotes%22";
    info.nShow  = SW_SHOWDEFAULT;

    if( !::ShellExecuteExW( &info ) )
    {
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
        printf("ShellExecuteEx failed with error %d\n", err );
    }

    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: You should also encode space characters as `%20` as well: `"http://www.google.de/search?q=ShellExecuteEx%20URL%20%22double%20quotes%22"`.  But more importantly, `lpVerb` should be `NULL` instead of `"open"` to launch the user's default browser.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why?

Comment: Because unencoded spaces are not allowed in a URL's query component, per [RFC 3986 Section 3.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4). A query can only have `pchar`, `/`, and `?` characters in it, and the definition of `pchar` does not include the unencoded space character. Any character not explicitly allowed in `pchar` must be percent-encoded instead, which is `%20` for a space character.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Fixed, thanks for the link. When testing the code it worked without encoding spaces, but ofc it's better to follow the spec.

Comment: Encoding the part containing the text resolved the issue. A huge thank you to all those who took the time to answer me